# Gap before header starts

Tags: css

There is some whitespace to the left of the header. How can i get rid of this?

```
.h {
    background: url('../Content/images/headlogo.png') no-repeat center;
    display: block;
    height: 93px;
    background-color: #D60024;
}
```

I want it to stretch from the beginning to the end.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4NkY5/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this too your CSS:

```
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is either the margin or the padding for the body or the whole html document, either set `html, body {maring:0; padding:0}` or use a css reset like Eric Meyer's.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4NkY5/5/)

```
 body{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
.h {
    display: block;
    height: 93px;
    background-color: #D60024;
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to reset styles is to set the margin and padding on all elements to zero

CSS Reset looks like this:

```
*{    
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

}

**[JSFiddle URL](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/4NkY5/4/)**